# Change example.jpg to example-color.jpg on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I wrote a script that would change example.jpg to example-color.jpg (.png, .gif would work too) on mouse hover and changes it back on mouse leave. I'm making a portfolio, and I have examples of my work in black and white thumbnails, on hover they switch to colored ones.

I'm just wondering if I did this in a redundant or 'wrong' way. is it poor how I have functions in variable, and to call it as such?

```
$(function () {
        var hoverImg = function() {
            var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
            var newSrc = imgSrc.slice(0, -4) + '-color.jpg';
            var isColor = imgSrc.split("-").pop();
            var notColor = (imgSrc.slice(0, - 10) +'.jpg');

            if ( isColor !== 'color.jpg' ) {
                $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
            } else {
                $(this).attr('src', notColor);
            }
         }
        var captionImg = function() {
            $(this).children('.gallery-caption').toggleClass('up');
         }

  $('.gallery').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.gallery-item img', hoverImg);   
 $('.gallery').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.gallery-item', captionImg);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

On another approach, you could do spriting. One problem you'll encounter with that approach, where you change src is that the image will take some time to load before the hover image appears. That's annoying. With sprites, you have one image just positioned differently on a container. There's no loading that will happen on hover.

[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/RMefw/). And the best part is... no JS!

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="image twitter"></a>
<a href="#" class="image facebook"></a>
```

CSS:

```
/* Class for setting the image */
.image {
    background-image: url("http://www.alexmourer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/css-sprite.png");
    display: block;
    width: 77px;
    height: 77px;
}

/* class for positioning to the right image (x and y) */
.image.twitter{
   background-position: 0 0;
}

.image.facebook{
   background-position: 308px 0;
}

/* class to offset the image on hover, in this case, up */
.image:hover{
    background-position-y: -154px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Joseph's idea of using sprites is certainly worth considering. It'll cut down on load times and avoid the hassle of preloading images, etc..

But to speak to your current code:

- Use a variable to store `$(this)` if you're going to be using it 2 or more times.
- Don't name a variable `isColor` unless it's a boolean value. In your case it's a string, but you could easily get a boolean value right away by doing something like

  ```
   var isColor = imgSrc.split("-").pop() == "color.jpg";
  ```
- Similarly, don't call the other variable `notColor`. Again, I'd expect this to be a boolean, but again it's a string. However, despite `isColor`/`notColor` seeming like 2 sides of the same coin, they in fact have nothing to do with each other. `isColor` is just a fragment of a URL, but `notColor` is full URL. Confusing. Call it something like "mouseleaveSrc"
- You say you might use png or gif images instead of jpg, but in that case, your code would have to change, since you rely on URLs ending in ".jpg". A more flexible solution would be to use a regular expression to match *a* file extension, rather than ".jpg" specifically.

---

As for refactoring, here's one possibility

```
$('.gallery-item img').each(function () {
  var img = $(this),
      src = img.attr("src");
  // use .data() to store the B/W and color urls for each image
  img.data({
    mouseenterSrc: src,
    mouseleaveSrc: src.replace(/(\.[a-z]{3,})$/i, "-color$1") // use a regexp to do the src-rewriting
  });
}).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (event) {
  var img = $(this);
  img.attr("src") = img.data(event.type + "Src"); // use the event type to figure out what to show
});
```